# Decorate a class in Python by defining the decorator as a class

Tags: python, decorator

What is a simple example of decorating a class by defining the decorator as a class?

I'm trying to achieve what has been implemented in Python 2.6 using [PEP 3129](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) except using classes not functions as Bruce Eckel explains [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845).

The following works:

```
class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def __call__(self, cls):
        def wrappedClass(*args):
            return cls(*args)
        return type("TestClass", (cls,), dict(newMethod=self.newMethod, classattr=self.arg))

    def newMethod(self, value):
        return value * 2

@Decorator("decorated class")
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "TestClass"
        print "init %s"%self.name

    def TestMethodInTestClass(self):
        print "test method in test class"

    def newMethod(self, value):
        return value * 3
```

Except, in the above, wrappedClass is not a class, but a function manipulated to return a class type. I would like to write the same callable as follows:

```
def __call__(self, cls):
        class wrappedClass(cls):
            def __init__(self):
                ... some code here ...
        return wrappedClass
```

How would this be done?

I'm not entirely sure what goes into *"""... some code here ..."""*

Comment: Did you try the code you posted yourself?  It should work.

Comment: The first part using the function does work. How would I write wrappedClass as a genuine class though?

Comment: What is your decorator supposed to do?  I cannot tell you what code has to go into "some code here" without knowing what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: I want to achieve what can be achieved with a function using a class. I understand this can be done, but couldn't find any examples to illustrate this

Comment: I don't get it.  The code in your second snippet should work as it is.  You can put just *any* code where "some code here" is.  How am I supposed to now what this code is supposed to do?  If you don't want to overwrite `__init__()`, simply don't.  If you *do* want to overwrite it, you obviously want to change its behaviour in some way.  I'm asking:  In what way?

Comment: The decorator should alter the method "newMethod" in TestClass which triples values to a method that just doubles values. In other words it has to replace the method in TestClass. I get my panties in a bunch soon after I declare __init__(self) and get confused by the Decorator's  reference to itself, the class (cls) I am decorating and the wrappedClass's self. HTH clear the confusion

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to overwrite `new_method()`, just do it:

```py
class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def __call__(self, cls):
        class Wrapped(cls):
            classattr = self.arg
            def new_method(self, value):
                return value * 2
        return Wrapped

@Decorator("decorated class")
class TestClass(object):
    def new_method(self, value):
        return value * 3
```

If you don't want to alter `__init__()`, you don't need to overwrite it.

Comment: Is there any scenario that we should decorate class instead of using class inheritance?

Answer (score 8):

After this, the class NormalClass becomes a ClassWrapper **instance**:

```
def decorator(decor_arg):

    class ClassWrapper:
        def __init__(self, cls):
            self.other_class = cls

        def __call__(self,*cls_ars):
            other = self.other_class(*cls_ars)
            other.field += decor_arg 
            return other

    return ClassWrapper

@decorator(" is now decorated.")
class NormalClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.field = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.field)
```

Test:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    A = NormalClass('A');
    B = NormalClass('B');

    print A
    print B
    print NormalClass.__class__
```

Output:

```
A is now decorated. <br>
B is now decorated. <br>
\__main__.classWrapper
```

Comment: you forgot to return the 'other' variable inside the __call__ method